# Angular.js promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angular-promise

I am confused about promise. I found the code below. What is the benefit of promise here. I have read about promise that it is used to **avoid callback hell**. Does promise provide **better performance** or is it just used to write the code in **readable format**?

```
     var list = function (params) {
            if (!params) {
                params = {};
            }
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (params.q) {
                params.q = JSON.stringify(params.q);
            }

            $http.get(someurl, {params: params}).success(function  (data, status, headers) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Comment: because the title is so vague, I've picked one of the many questions about Promises to make this a duplicate of. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20what%20are%20promises

Answer (score 0):

`Promise`s are used as handles to asynchronous code. You can later use this (as a variable name) to check the success.

Docs say:

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.

Also read:

[$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

[$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

Promises are used to make code more readable, better organized (avoid spaghetti code), and more flexible.

However, that example you have there is using a bad technique known as the "[deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)". A better way to accomplish the same thing would be:

```
var list = function (params) {
    if (!params) {
        params = {};
    }
    if (params.q) {
        params.q = JSON.stringify(params.q);
    }

    return $http.get(someurl, {params: params}).then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
    });
};
```